# Slow listView due to weird SQLite database setup. Looking for an efficient way to handle this

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite, android-cursoradapter, android-cursorloader

I have a very specific problem. I'm creating a word list app that basically lets me enter some words and their meanings and stores them in an SQLite database and then it shows them back to me. I've made my own content provider to handle all these interactions. I store the words in one table and the definitions in another table and these two tables are linked together through the books' unique id. I'm also using a CursorLoader and a CursorAdapter to populate my listView in my MainActivity. Now my problem is when I get the list of the words that I have in my database, some of the words have more than one definition and I have to query against the database as I'm drawing each list item in my listView to find the definitions and put them on the list. This has caused my listView to stutter. I've even tried to use AsyncTask but I don't want to start a new thread every time a word is getting added to my listView at runtime. Is there any efficient, right way to do this?

This is my CursorAdapter class where I believe is the source of the problem.

```
public class WordAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

public static final String[] definitionsProjection = {
        Definitions._ID,
        Definitions.COLUMN_TEXT,
        Definitions.COLUMN_POS
};

public static final String[] examplesProjection = {
        Examples._ID,
        Examples.COLUMN_TITLE,
        Examples.COLUMN_TEXT,
        Examples.COLUMN_URL
};

public static final int DEFINITIONS_COLUMN_TEXT = 1;
public static final int DEFINITIONS_COLUMN_POS = 2;

public static final int EXAMPLES_COLUMN_TITLE = 1;
public static final int EXAMPLES_COLUMN_TEXT = 2;
public static final int EXAMPLES_COLUMN_URL = 3;

private static final int VIEW_TYPE_TODAY = 0;
private static final int VIEW_TYPE_OLD = 1;

public WordAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context, c, flags);
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(position == 0) {
        return VIEW_TYPE_TODAY;
    } else {
        return VIEW_TYPE_OLD;
    }
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

    int viewType = getItemViewType(cursor.getPosition());
    int layoutId = -1;

    if(viewType == VIEW_TYPE_TODAY) {
        layoutId = R.layout.list_item_today;
    } else if(viewType == VIEW_TYPE_OLD) {
        layoutId = R.layout.list_item_word;
    }

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layoutId, parent, false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    view.setTag(viewHolder);

    return view;

}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    int viewType = getItemViewType(cursor.getPosition());

    String wordId = cursor.getString(MainFragment.WORDS_ID);

    viewHolder.wordView.setText(wordId + " / " + cursor.getString(MainFragment.WORDS_COLUMN_WORD));

    FetchDefinitions fetchDefinitions = new FetchDefinitions(context, view);
    fetchDefinitions.execute(wordId);

    switch (viewType) {
        case VIEW_TYPE_TODAY:
        {
            viewHolder.noteView.setText(cursor.getString(MainFragment.WORDS_COLUMN_NOTE));

            Cursor exampleCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                    Examples.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(wordId).build(),
                    examplesProjection,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null
            );

            exampleCursor.moveToFirst();

            viewHolder.exampleOneView.setText(exampleCursor.getString(EXAMPLES_COLUMN_TITLE));

            if(exampleCursor.getCount() > 1) {
                exampleCursor.moveToNext();
                viewHolder.exampleTwoView.setText(exampleCursor.getString(EXAMPLES_COLUMN_TITLE));
            } else {
                viewHolder.exampleTwoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            exampleCursor.close();

            break;
        }

    }

    viewHolder.flagView.setText("Flag " + Utility.flagsToString(cursor.getInt(MainFragment.WORDS_COLUMN_FLAG)));
    viewHolder.sourceView.setText("Source " + cursor.getString(MainFragment.WORDS_COLUMN_SOURCE));
    viewHolder.dateView.setText(Utility.convertDateToUXFormat(cursor.getInt(MainFragment.WORDS_COLUMN_DATE)));

}

private static class ViewHolder {

    public final TextView wordView;
    public final TextView noteView;
    public final TextView exampleOneView;
    public final TextView exampleTwoView;
    public final TextView flagView;
    public final TextView sourceView;
    public final TextView dateView;

    private ViewHolder(View view) {

        wordView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.word_textView);
        noteView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.note_textView);
        exampleOneView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.example_1_textView);
        exampleTwoView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.example_2_textView);
        flagView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.flag_textView);
        sourceView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.source_textView);
        dateView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date_textView);

    }

}

private class FetchDefinitions extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Cursor> {

    private Context bgContext;
    private View bgView;

    public TextView posOneView;
    public TextView posTwoView;
    public TextView definitionOneView;
    public TextView definitionTwoView;

    public FetchDefinitions(Context context, View view) {
        this.bgContext = context;
        this.bgView = view;
    }

    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(String... params) {
        String wordId = params[0];
        return bgContext.getContentResolver().query(
                Definitions.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(wordId).build(),
                definitionsProjection,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Cursor cursor) {

        if(cursor != null) {

            cursor.moveToFirst();

            posOneView = (TextView) bgView.findViewById(R.id.pos_1_textView);
            definitionOneView = (TextView) bgView.findViewById(R.id.definition_1_textView);

            posOneView.setText(cursor.getString(DEFINITIONS_COLUMN_POS));
            definitionOneView.setText(cursor.getString(DEFINITIONS_COLUMN_TEXT));

            posTwoView = (TextView) bgView.findViewById(R.id.pos_2_textView);
            definitionTwoView = (TextView) bgView.findViewById(R.id.definition_2_textView);

            if(cursor.getCount() > 1) {
                cursor.moveToNext();
                posTwoView.setText(cursor.getString(DEFINITIONS_COLUMN_POS));
                definitionTwoView.setText(cursor.getString(DEFINITIONS_COLUMN_TEXT));
            } else {
                posTwoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                definitionTwoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        }

    }

}

}
```

Comment: Being more specific would improve your chances of receiving an useful answer. For instance, you could show the piece of code where you think your problem is.

Comment: @Bonifacio2 Thanks. I just added the code I believe is the root of the problem.